# Reporting Services Exporting Problems

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on a Microsoft Dynamics CRM Quote with a separate header report and sub report.

The sub-report has a detail grid of what is quote, a terms and conditions statement which amounts to a large block of text, and other items.

When the report shows on screen, the Quote looks just like I intended. However, when I export to Word or PDF the long text block of terms and conditions will not print until the second page and there is a lot of white space on page 1. I set "Keep Together" on that text box to false, but that does not make a difference.

Also, I am getting blank pages in between worthwhile pages containing text and I think this is because one of my objects is too wide horizontally to print on paper.

Can anyone help me with the following questions:

1. What is the best way to know whether what you are authoring will spill over to more pages horizontally?
2. How do I set the large block of text not to begin a new page if it does not fit? I can't seem to find the setting. Is my only option to divide this large text box into many smaller boxes?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into similar issues before with wide reports. One of the easiest things to fiddle with are the margins in the report itself. This can be configured in

`Report > Properties > Margins`